# Mocha test cases throwing Error: expected 200 "OK", got 403 "Forbidden"

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mocha.js, mean

I am using mochajs for my mean applications server side test cases.The test cases are showing an error, `Error: expected 200 "OK", got 403 "Forbidden"`.
I tried using console logs inside the functions that I am trying to test, but they never get executed. I am unable to find out the issue. Can someone help me with this.

**My controller**

```
exports.signin = function(req, res) {
   req.body.username = new Buffer(req.body.username, base64').toString('ascii');
    User.findOne({
        username: req.body.username.toLowerCase()
    }, function(err, user) {
        if (err) {
            //do something
        } else if (!user) {
            //do something
        } else {
            //do something
        }
    });
};
```

**My test case**

```
it('should be able to signin if the credentials are valid', function(done) {
    var obj = {
        username: new Buffer('demo').toString('base64'),
        password: new Buffer('demouser').toString('base64')
        };
    agent.post('/auth/signin')
        .send(obj)
        .expect(200)
        .end(function(signinErr, res) {
                if (signinErr){
                      console.log(signinErr);
                    done(signinErr);
                }
                else{
                    var temp = res.body;
                    console.log(temp);
            done();
                }
    });
});
```

**And my route**

```
app.route('/auth/signin').post(users.signin);
```

Comment: Its because of you are expecting 200 `.expect(200)`  but your authentication fails and you end up getting 403. Check the username/password that you are sending.

Comment: My parameters are correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was facing the same issue. I found out that we were forcing SSL in our application using the middleware `express-force-ssl` by `app.use(force-ssl)`. We used a flag to control this behavior. When I made that false, the test cases ran fine.
So if you are not controlling it with the flag. Try removing that module and running your test cases.